# Cast date to DD.MM.YY from XML in AJAX

Tags: xml, arrays, jquery, date, casting

I am building an aggregator that takes news stories from XML and outputs them as individual LI's.

I need to cast the data for the date (currently outputs as `Mon, 16 Dec 2013 11:00:00 GMT`) into a numerical format so that I can then run queries on the date.

For example I need to:

- Select the 10 most recent items from the array
- Store these in a sub-array
- Randomise the sub-array and output

Essentially so the last 10 news stories are taken and then randomised.

The code so far is working [here](http://www.sagittarius-digital.com/sag-aggregator/sag-aggregator.html) (takes 5 seconds to load) and is generated by:

```
<script>
      jQuery(function(){
        $.ajax({
          url: 'http://www.sagittarius-digital.com/news.rss',
          dataType: 'xml'
        }).done(function(xml){
          var items = $(xml).find('item').map(function(){
                var $item = $(this);
                var array = '<li class="ourNewsItem">';
                array += '<a href="' + $item.find('link').text() + '">';
                array += '<h2>' + $item.find('title').text() + '</h2>';
                array += '<p>' + $item.find('description').text() + '</p>';
                array += '<p>' + $item.find('pubDate').text() + '</p>';
                array += '<p>Category: ' + $item.find('category').text() + '</p>';
                array += '</a>';
                array += '</li>';
                return array;
          }).get();
          $('ul').append(items.join(' '));
        }).fail(function(){
          console.log('error', arguments)
        })
      })
</script>
```

Comment: item.find('pubDate').text is a string, so you need to convert it to a date type, then format that in the way you want it. Note YYYYMMDD would probably be a better choice than dd.mm.yy.

Comment: Do you have any examples of this being done? I am a bit new to this. Just looking for the correct way to cast the data.

Comment: Jquery is not my thing, yet. No doubt someone will be along shortly

Comment: if you search on here for "jquery date", loads of stuff. Such as this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-a-json-date